# Plotting with xmgrace using bash

Tags: bash, scripts, plot

I'm using Xmgrace to plot my data.
I wanted to make my life easier and I started to write a bash script, so I don't have to plot the data manually.

In order to save the figures, I wrote this to the code:

```
device "eps" op "level2"
print to "../figs/name.eps"
print
```

This command generates the eps: `xmgrace -batch nameoffile.bfile -nosafe`
When I run this command, Xmgrace opens, an error message pops up
"[Error] Unknown device: DEVICE "eps" OP "level2"
, and it generates the necessary eps-file.

I have other an other problem as well and up until this point I wasn't able to solve it. I made a script to convert all necessary data to eps figures. 
The program Xmgrace opens every time with the error message (and with the figure). I have to close it manually (it's really unpleasant after the sixth closure). Is there a way to close Xmgrace program in bash?
It would be even better if I also could save the data in "*.agr" before closing Xmgrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g*number1*x*number2* -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=Filename.pdf *.eps
```

Use this command.